# Project in Eclipse that builds a jar used by another project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have several projects open in Eclipse.  One of them is the main app, and others build jars used by that main app.  How do I make it so that when I hit F3 on a method call in the main app that it takes me to the source in the other project instead of taking me to the class file in the Libraries list?  I got it so that it shows me the source, but I can't actually edit it like it could if I go to the other project, and similarly when I step through in the debugger it doesn't go into the editable code.

I don't know if it's relevant, but we're using Maven to handle the dependencies.

I know this should be simple, but I haven't found the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of including the other projects' jars in the main app on its library path, include the projects as dependencies in the "Projects" tab inside the Project Properties dialog.

Comment: I had to go into "Order and Export" and move the projects up above "Maven Dependencies", but that appears to have done the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click the JAR file on your main project, you can use "Attach Source" option to use F3 to navigate to methods when needed.

Comment: That's what I did before - I get a read-only view of the source in a tab labelled "foo.class".